# CGPointFromString in Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, cgpoint

Is there an equivalent function available in Xamarin.iOS for [CGPointFromString](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/1624477-cgpointfromstring)

I looked at online Xamarin API documents and nothing that I found relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not any built in method for equivalent to CGPointFromString in Xamarin.iOS. You can use following to get CGPoint from string.

```
        String str = "{23,213}";
        str = str.Replace('{', '');
        str = str.Replace('}', '');

        string[] coord = str.Split(',');
        CoreGraphics.CGPoint pt = new CoreGraphics.CGPoint(Int64.Parse(coord[0]), Int64.Parse(coord[1]);
```

Comment: I ended up doing something like this....`List<CGPoint> points = new List<CGPoint>();
     for (int index = 0; index < pts.Length; index++)
     {
      CGPoint p = new CGPoint();
      p.X = Convert.ToSingle(pts[index].Split(',')[0]);
      p.Y = Convert.ToSingle(pts[index].Split(',')[1]);
      points.Add(p);
     }` where pts is an Array with values like `"[x1,y1],[x2,y2],[x3,y3],....[xn,yn]"`